# How can we prove that we can get any $f$ modulo a prime $p$, that satisfies these equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, intuition, constraints

We can suppose that we have four naturals not equal to zero: $a, b, c, d$.  Further, we're working modulo a prime $p$.

Now if we find $a, b, c, d$ that satisfy:

$$f \equiv a \cdot c \equiv b \cdot d \ne 0, \mod p \tag{1}$$
$$g \equiv a \cdot d \equiv b \cdot c \ne 0, \mod p \tag{2}$$
$$\text{and } a \cdot c \ne b \cdot c, \tag{3}$$

It seems to me (from experiments) that $f$ always must equal $p-g$.  Further, we can find numbers that can make equations (1), (2) and (3) true for any $f$ not equal to $0$.

Can someone prove this?  In other words, can someone prove that we can satisfy the above equations for any given $f$ modulo $p$?  Also, can we prove that $f \equiv p-g$?

**MY IDEAS**

If we solve $a \cdot c = b \cdot d$, we find $a = \frac{bd}{c}$.  Then, plugging in $a$ into $a \cdot d = b \cdot c$, we find $d^2 \equiv c^2 \mod p$.  Similarly, solving (1) for $c$, we find $c = \frac{bd}{a}$.  Then, plugging into $a \cdot d = b \cdot c$, we find $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod p$.  So I believe we can collect the terms as:

$$c^2 \equiv d^2 \mod p \tag{4}$$
$$a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod p \tag{5}$$

I'm not sure where to proceed from here.  Perhaps there is another approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ ac\not\equiv bc\,\Rightarrow\, a\not\equiv b,\,$ so $\, 0\equiv a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a+b\equiv 0},\,$ therefore $\,f+g \equiv ac+bc = (\color{#c00}{a+b})c\equiv 0,\,$ so $\,f\equiv -g.$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, +1.  Is there a way to prove that we can get _any_ $f$ modulo $p$?  It may seem trivial, but I really need this proved, too.

Comment: @Matt Which symbols are fixed and which are variable, i.e. what are you solving for?

Comment: $a, b, c, d$ are variable.  They can be anything you like except $0$.  I simply need to prove that I can get any $f$ value under the constraints of (1), (2) and (3).  So really only $f$ is fixed or given.  I guess this should be easy, but I'm not sure how to prove it.  If you show this I will certainly accept your answer!

Comment: @Matt The equations imply $\,a+b\equiv 0\equiv c+d\,$ hence $\,b\equiv -a,\ d\equiv -c\,$ therefore the equations are $(1)\ \ f\equiv ac\equiv (-a)(-c)\,$ and $(2)\ \ g\equiv a(-c)\equiv (-a)c.\,$ So to get $f$ e.g. choose $\,a\equiv f,\ c\equiv 1.$