# What values or form of values can we get for these multiplications modulo a prime?

Tags: complex-numbers, intuition, constraints

If we have four complex values, all of the form $a + b i$, for integers $a$ and $b$, we can label them $c$, $d$, $e$ and $f$.  Now if we want to find $g$ and $h$ such that

$$g \equiv ce \equiv df \mod p$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$h \equiv de \equiv cf \mod p$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$g \ne h \mod p$$

I'm wondering what values we can get for $g$ and $h$, given that we can pick any $c$, $d$, $e$ and $f$, or what form they'll take.

**UPDATE**

**I believe that we can have any combination (of $g$ and $h$) that satisfies $g^2 \equiv (h^2) \mod p$.  Can anyone prove this?**

**AN EXAMPLE**

For instance, if we pick $c=i, d=4i, e=i, f=4i$ we get $$g \equiv -1 \mod p$$ and $$h \equiv 1 \mod p$$.

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR**

I'm looking to find every possible combination of $g$ and $h$, or what form the two will take on.

**PROBLEM SOURCE**

The formulas come from observing the following multiplications:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
* & c & d \\
\hline
e & ce & de \\
\hline
f & cf & df
\end{array}
$$

What we're after, then, is:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
* & c & d \\
\hline
e & g & h \\
\hline
f & h & g
\end{array}
$$

Comment: If this differs from your [prior question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/726418/242) then it would be helpful to explicitly say how it differs.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  _This time I'm working with complex numbers._  I've found that with complex numbers, we can have $g \ne -h \mod p$.  For example, if we have $c=i$, $d=2$, $e=2i$, and $f=4$, then $g \equiv 3 \mod 5$ and $h \equiv -i \mod 5$.  _I want to find all combinations for arbitrary $p$_.

Comment: What is the source of these problems? Providing such context might help you get more focused answers.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I'm working on an algorithm to solve SAT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) faster.  I've added a section showing where the multiplications come from.  Unfortunately, the ideas/motivation behind these multiplications is very complicated.  I am hoping that the explanation in the problem is enough.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I think I've found what the combinations can be, which I've added in the update section.  Perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible proof to the question - I need someone to check my work.

We start with $g \equiv ce \equiv df \mod p$.  So

$$\begin{align}
ce &\equiv df \mod p \\
c &\equiv df/e \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

We also have $h \equiv de \equiv cf \mod p$.  So

$$\begin{align}
de &\equiv (c)f \mod p \\
&\equiv (df/e)f \qquad \text{using (1)}\\
&\equiv df^2/e \\
e &\equiv f^2/e \\
e^2 &\equiv f^2 \mod p \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Now if we start with:

$$
\begin{align}
(ce)^2 &\equiv c^2 e^2 \\
&\equiv c^2 f^2 \qquad \text{ from (2)} \\
(ce)^2 &\equiv (cf)^2 \\
g^2 &\equiv h^2
\end{align}
$$

Could someone please verify that this is correct?